# Merge config files with esm modules

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm building a CSS framework and I need a way to merge user config file and the framework default config file when a user installs my framework using npm. I tried with procces.cwd but there is a problem when I want to export that file since I use it in the class generation function. By default, the framework creates a config file inside the user's root folder, where
the framework is installed using npm. Also i tryed using async function for await user config file and then merging but i cant use it after because of export. Also if you guys have time you can check whole project on [github](https://github.com/bodafoo/storboatcss)

```js
import colors from './colors.config.js'
import { merge } from '../util/merge.js'

const defaultConfig = {
    reset: false,
    theme: {
        screens: {
            sm: '(min-width: 640px)',
            md: '(min-width: 768px)',
            lg: '(min-width: 1024px)',
            xl: '(min-width: 1280px)',
            xxl: '(min-width: 1536px)',
        },
        colors: {
            ...colors,
        },
    },
}

// Just for testing purpose
import userConfig from '../../storboat.config.js'

const config = merge(defaultConfig, userConfig)

export default config
```

I tried with procces.cwd

Comment: In this case, you'de be better off using `import()` and throwing if there's no file.

Comment: But i need way of getting user config file. I need something like rootDir = process.cwd() and then userConfig = path.resolve(rootDir, 'storboat.config.js')

Answer (score 0):

I found a way, it need to use async await of promise.

```js
async function loadUserConfig() {
    const userConfigRootPath = process.cwd()
    const userConfigPath = path.resolve(userConfigRootPath, './storboat.config.js')
    try {
        const userConfigModule = await import(userConfigPath)
        return userConfigModule.default || userConfigModule
    } catch {
        return {}
    }
}

const userConfigPromise = loadUserConfig()

const configPromise = userConfigPromise.then((userConfig) => {
    const config = merge(defaultConfig, userConfig)
    return config
})

export default configPromise
```